# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] returning current page instead of previous page?

Tags: php

I am wanting to get the previous page url and I read that the below will get the previous url, but it is getting the current url?

```
<?php
    $prev = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    echo $prev;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: TL;DR on the dupe: Don't rely on `HTTP_REFERRER`. It's inconsistent at best

Comment: Thx. I ended up using getenv('HTTP_REFERER'); and worked.